# How to check invalid json input in mule?

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio

how to check input JSON is in correct format or not in mule
my input JSON is

```
{
    "received": "3538410873",
    "RmaNumber": "93321"2",
    "TrackingNumber": "324823478",
    "DeviceMake": "samsung",
    "DeviceModel": "j7 prime",
    "DeviceColor": "black"
}
```

I tried with is-json-filter but it is not working

```
<message-filter onUnaccepted="noJsonFlow" throwOnUnaccepted="false">
    <json:is-json-filter />
</message-filter>
```

I need to show invalid JSON format for invalid JSON input

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives you could use, each with some small drawbacks.

You could use a  with an empty schema definition (ie a file containing only `{}`). It will detect the error in my tests and not reject a valid JSON. It seems to be a bit of hack to me.

Another option is to use a DataWeave transfomer to just the same payload. It will validate before transformation. The cons are that it will transform to an equivalent , which is overkill, and less performant because it does double work, but also could be formatted a bit differently than the original. This might or not be an issue for you. You could avoid it by assigning the result to flowVar.
Example:

```
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json"/> <!-- only needed if the mimetype is not set for the payload -->
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

The third option is to create your own [custom validator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/building-a-custom-validator) and use a Java library to validate JSON as you wish. The only cons I see is that it needs a bit more work because it is not OOTB.